# Qualifier usage in Pattern

Tags: java, android, regex

I'm confused by qualifier usage in java's pattern:
The first piece of code:

```
private void testRegex(String patternString) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("::::::::");
        if (matcher.find()) {
            Log.d("regex", matcher.group());
        } else {
            Log.d("regex", "not match");
    }
}
```

Then I try `testRegex(":?")`, `testRegex(":*")`, `testRegex(":+")` respectively;
result is:

```
":","::::::::","::::::::";
```

It is absolutely correct I know, BUT:

I try another piece of code below:

```
private void testRegex(String patternString) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("sip::::::::");
        if (matcher.find()) {
            Log.d("regex", matcher.group());
        } else {
            Log.d("regex", "not match");
    }
}
```

Result is:

```
""(empty String),""(empty String),"::::::::"
```

Who can tell me what on Earth happened? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `?` and `*` operators also have the *zero occurrence* part in their functionality, and when the first character is not matched, they will stop there because they match `0` times, which is allowed.

```
:?
```

[image: Regular expression image]

```
:*
```

[image: Regular expression image]

[See that they have a route to bypass `:`]

```
:+
```

[image: Regular expression image]

In the case of `:+` it can only try 1, or more, which means it tries to find this existent 1 occurrence of `:` and once it has it, it consumes all the following `:` if it can find them. There's no route to bypass the `:`.

Comment: really vivid!and can I ask how to make a diagram like this?

Comment: @user1242027 A fellow user of SO showed it to me ^^ Visit [debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/)